# Default SSL context init failed: null

Tags: java, ssl

When creating a SSL server, I got this exception: `Default SSL context init failed: null`. It seems that it comes from the fact it can't find the keystore and truststore. I try to set them from a jar file. The file exists in the jar but it seems that the resource cannot be found.

```
String keystore = TestFramework.class.getResource("/security/keystore.jks").getFile();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
String truststore = TestFramework.class.getResource("/security/truststore").getFile();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truststore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "ebxmlrr");
```

I ran a `ls` command to check if the file exists. It exists. Then I check if the keystore.jks exists by running the command `jar -tf myjar.jar | grep security` and it exists.

```
security/
security/keystore.jks
security/truststore
```

My application is running under Tomcat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that won't work is that those system properties are expecting a file on the actual filesystem, not from within an archive. You'd be better off creating your own [`SSLContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) using those keystore and trustore streams:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
keyStore.load(TestFramework.class.getResourceAsStream("/security/keystore.jks"), password.toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
trustStore.load(TestFramework.class.getResourceAsStream("/security/truststore"), "ebxmlrr".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

...

HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Just a minor comment, the load method needs an InputStream instead of a URL. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fixed. That's what I get for adapting code without compiling it.