# SocketException Default SSL context is null while connecting to remote server

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, certificate

I am facing the following `SSL` connection `exception` when trying to connect to remote server:

```
java.net.SocketException: Default SSL context init failed: null
```

Most of the thread suggest that there is some problem with the `keystore` location that contains the `certificate` file.

Others like this post:  [**Default SSL context init failed: null**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927733/default-ssl-context-init-failed-null)  suggests is to create the `SSL Context` by yourself. But, again the issue is not resolved yet.

**And here is what I did so far:**

I tried to add `certificate` to the following file locations and all of them gave me the same error mentioned earlier:

•   `Cacerts` file in `Java Home`.

•   Default `cacerts` location for the `IDE` I am using (`JDveloper 10.1.3.2`) which is in my case : `C:\JDeveloper\WorkSpace_10g\jdevstudio10132\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts`

•   New `keystore` that only contains this `certificate`.

The `certificated` is added using `Portecle` applet( I also tried `keytool` options from `Command prompts`)

I am also referring to the `trustStore` and `keyStore` in the code as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore file path goes here);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password goes here);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore file path goes here);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password goes here);
```

In the above code the `file path` refer for the `cacerts` files mentioned earlier (`Java home`, default `JDeveloper` `cacerts` and newly created `keystore`) of course I tried each one separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keystore isn't found. Check that you can open that file from within the same piece of code by the same name you're using in `javax.net.ssl.keyStore.`

If you're using the default `cacerts` you don't need to set `javax.net.ssl.trustStore/trustStorePassword` at all.

Comment: I missed the file extension in the path  `.jks` for the newly created `keystore `file.